# Generating a non-repeating set from a random seed, and extract result by index

Tags: algorithm, random, sequence

*p.s. I have referred to this as `Random`, but this is a Seed Based Random Shuffle, where the Seed will be generated by a PRNG, but with the same Seed, the same "random" distribution will be observed.*

I am currently trying to find a method to assist in doing 2 things:

### 1) Generate Non-Repeating Sequence

This will take 2 arguments: `Seed`; and `N`. It will generate a sequence, of size `N`, populated with numbers between `1` and `N`, with no repetitions.

I have found a few good methods to do this, but most of them get stumped by feasibility with the second thing.

### 2) Extract an entry from the Sequence

This will take 3 arguments: `Seed`; `N`; and `I`. This is for determining what value would appear at position `I` in a Sequence that would be generated with `Seed` and `N`. However, in order to work with what I have in mind, it absolutely cannot use a generated sequence, and pick out an element.

I initially worked with pre-calculating the sequence, then querying it, but this only really works in test cases, as the number of `Seeds`, and the value of `N` that will be used would create a database into the Petabytes.

From what I can tell, having a method that implements requirement 1 by using requirement 2 would be the most ideal method.

i.e. a sequence is generated by:

```
function Generate_Sequence(int S, int N) {
    int[] sequence = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        sequence[i] = Extract_From_Sequence(S, N, i);
    }
    return sequence;
}
```

## For Example

```
GS = Generate Sequence
ES = Extract from Sequence

for:
 S = 1
 N = 5
 I = 4

GS(S, N) = { 4, 2, 5, 1, 3 }
ES(S, N, I) = 1

let S = 2

GS(S, N) = { 3, 5, 2, 4, 1 }
ES(S, N, I) = 4
```

Comment: 1.) `[1, 2, 3 ... N].random_sort()`

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the second case? I don't quite get what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Lingxi sounds like a lazy sequence (generator) for cases when N wouldn't fit into memory

Comment: If the sequence is random, does it matter what value `I` assumes?

Comment: @Lingxi if true randomness doesn't need a seed, then it's more likely OP is talking about reproducible deterministic pseudorandom sequence

Comment: @Aprillion except they want an O(1) access to it, it seems. I imagine random sampling of some huge database, which (sampling) must be non-repeating.

Comment: @WillNess how did you infer the `O(1)` requirement for access to arbitrary `I`? and even if they really wanted it (as opposed to, say, `O(logn)`, or if `I` would be accessed as a monotonic sequence), that wouldn't be compatible with the explicit requirement of *absolutelly cannot pre-calculate the sequence* so one of those requirements have to go

Comment: @Aprillion There recently was similar question about  non-repeated pseudo-random sequence, and the answer was, do it by random shuffling. But for it to work, the input sequence must actually get shuffled.  the OP says they want to "extract an entry from the Sequence that *would* get randomly generated", without actually generating the Sequence. I thought it meant directly calculating it, i.e. "O(1)". But only the OP knows what they want. :) --- I gave my imagined scenario above: huge B-Tree which must be predictably, pseudo-randomly sampled w/ no repetitions. Predictable pseudo-rand shuffling.

Comment: http://preshing.com/20121224/how-to-generate-a-sequence-of-unique-random-integers/ looks promising

Comment: Essentially, what I am looking to do is, where `S` is the random seed (being generated as needed) but if the same value is used, it will generate the same Sequence. `I` refers to the position in the sequence, i.e. if you did `GEN_SEQ(123, 10)`, you would have a sequence of 10 numbers, and that would always be the same for `S = 123`, then, if you did `FETCH_GEN_SEQ(123, 10, 3)`, it would be as if you did `GEN_SEQ` from before, then chose element 3. The point being, in production, there will be 100s of unique `S`'s, `N` is about a trillion, and `I` varies between 1 and `N`

Comment: Is an `O(I)` runtime unacceptable for `FETCH_GEN_SEQ`

Comment: @pseudoDust Sadly not, I think I know what you were thinking, but in some cases, `I` will go as high as trillions, and be running in a non-sequential fashion...

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to make a permutation over the bit positions of the number. Assume that N is a power of two (I will discuss the general case later!).
Use the seed S to generate a permutation \sigma over the set of {1,2,...,log(n)}. Then permute the bits of I according to the \sigma to obtain I'. In other words, the bit of I' at the position \sigma(x) is obtained from the bit of I at the position x.
One problem with this method is its linearity (It is closed under the XOR operation). To overcome this, you can find a number p with gcd(p,N)=1 (this can be done easily even for very large Ns) and generate a random number (q < N) using the seed S. The output of the Extract_From_Sequence(S, N, I) would be (p*I'+q mod N).

Now the case where N is not a complete power of two. The problem arises when the I' falls outside the range of [1,N]. In that case, we return the most significant bits of I to their initial position until the resulting value falls into the desired range. This is done by changing the \sigma(log(n)) bit of I' with the log(n) bit, and so on ....